Saddle point of a multivariable function.
How to show that the functions $f(x,y )= x^2- \frac{3}{2}xy^2$ and $g(x,y)= 4x^4 -5x^2y +y^2$ have saddle point at the origin $(0,0$)? For the first function $f(x,y), $ I choose the path $y=0$ along which it has a local minimum at $(0,0)$ but is unable to choose the path of the local maximum. Similar to the second function I can choose path $y=-x^2$ long which has a local minimum. Is there more suitable way? How to choose a second path? Thank you.

Please revisit the definition of Saddle Point.

f: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwly70KgzAUhuE9V%5FHhksSeWH%2Dg27mHDJ0FqRGlaiTaNunVFym8w7O87y4oGSlJLQYwYlvDoLnWecxTWwsLxjb7o%2DnVQFCRYMriRqg0QSWCqf5e3D7yPbycFhYXxuan9ZxUSTjThH36Oq5KwsPPPnAWXJ9pYYt99B91jG5xLPsuPKUWPylqJ6Q=&lang=sage g: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw1y7EKgzAURuE9T%5FHjkkSvEq2O9x0cOgtSg0rVSLRt0qcvDoWzfMN5917JQFFqMYJRp6GrkaNJQ1elERliV4kWjH1x521QI0EFQm6KhmCKRhNU%5FLvUhNUeE9%5F9y2rRImPsbt6uURnClSYc89dyaQgPtzjPibdDokVbHJP7qHOyq2U59P4ptfgBkQQp3g==&lang=sage

Notice that $g(x,y)=(4x^2-y)(x^2-y)$. If both factors are positive, you will have $g>0$; if one factor is positive and the other is negative, you will have $g<0$. Since the parabolas $y=x^2$ and $y=4x^2$ intersect at the origin, it is clear that you have points arbitrarily close to the origin with $g$ of both signs. This means that the origin is a saddle point.
In this case, you can do something similar — algebraically — with the function $f$. Note that $f(x,y) = x(x-\frac32y^2)$. So, with points $(x,y)$ having $0<x<\frac32y^2$, you will have $f(x,y)<0$. And you can find plenty of points arbitrarily close to the origin with $f(x,y)>0$.
EDIT: You have not responded to my request for an actual definition. But it is easy to find curves through the origin on which the functions are $\ge 0$ and $\le 0$, respectively.  For example, for $g$, take either $x=0$ or $y=0$ and then $y=2x^2$ (which is in the negative region I described).

How we have both sign along $y=x^2$ and $y=4x^2$. It is zero along these ?

Yes,  but so what? What is the definition of a saddle point?

these two curves must intersects transversely

You’re missing the point. These two curves are not the answer to anything. Edit your post to include the precise textbook definition of a saddle point.

A Course in Multivariable Calculus and Analysis (Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics) Paperback – 10 December 2009
by Sudhir R. Ghorpade (Author), Balmohan V. Limaye (Author)

I asked for the definition your book gives of a saddle point. The usual definition, which I'm referring to in my answer, is that in every neighborhood of the point $P$ there are points where the function value is bigger than $f(P)$ and points where the function value is smaller than $f(P)$.

then according to your book definition it’s neither Max nor min . I think it is not a saddle point . Like  $f(x,y)= x^3$, origin is not a saddle point .

I do not follow you. You still have not given me your book's actual precise definition. By all the definitions I know, yes, the origin is a saddle point of $f(x,y)=x^3$.

Definition: Let $D \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ and let $(x_0,y_0)$ be an interior point of D. We say that a function $f : D\to\mathbb R$ has saddle point at $(x_0, y_0)$ if there are regular paths $C_1$ and $C_2$ lying in $D$ and intersecting transversally at $(x_0, y_0)$ such that $f$ has a local maximum at $(x_0,y_0)$ along $C_1$, while f has a local minimum at $(x_0,y_0)$ along $C_2$.

The same book has an example which proves that $f(x,y)=x^3$ does not have a saddle point at the origin. Unable to type full solved example.

OK, it's an unusual definition. You should probably edit your question to include that in the question. Nevertheless, I've answered your question. By analyzing where the function is positive, zero, and negative, you can certainly choose paths (that intersect transversely) with the desired properties. I showed you one possibility for $g$.

ok I will edit it ......

First you need to find critical points, that is the points where $\nabla f(x,y)=0$, from there you will have two equations: $f_x(x,y)=0$ and $f_y(x,y)=0$. Solve them and you will find the critical points. After that you have to set up the Hessian matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
f_{xx}&f_{xy}\\
f_{yx}&f_{yy}
\end{bmatrix},$$
whose determinant is $D(x,y)=f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}f_{yx}$. Evaluate $D$ at your critial points. If you get a negative value, then you have a saddle point. Do exactly the same with $g(x,y)$ and that's it.

No, that isn't it. What if $D=0$?

Oh, since he was asking about saddle points I just stated the criteria for a saddle points, but if D=0 this test is inconclusive.

The common approach in these type of questions is to use the Hessian matrix and the Sylvester's criterion. If you can prove that Hessian matrix is indefinite, that is the justification to call a critical point a saddle point.
Take $f(x,y)=x^2-\frac{3}{2}xy$ for instance. Its derivatives are:
$$
\begin{array}{}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &=& 2x-\frac{3}{2}y^2\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &=& -3xy \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} &=& -3y \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} &=& 2 \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} &=& -3x\\
\end{array}
$$
From the first two equations one learns that the only critical point $P$ is $(0, 0)$. The rest form the Hessian matrix:
$$ H=
\begin{pmatrix}{}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} &
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} &
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}{}
2 & -3y \\
-3y  & - 3x
\end{pmatrix}
$$
From here it goes:
$$
H\bigg|_{(0,0)} = 
\begin{pmatrix}{}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, to the Sylvester's criterion:
A matrix $M$ is positive-definite if all of the leading principal minors are positive and negative-definite if all the consecutive leading principal minors $\Delta_{i}$ change their signs with $\Delta_1 = M_{11}$ being negative.
As you can see in case of $f(x,y)$, the second principal minor $\Delta_2 = 2 \cdot 0 - 0 \cdot 0 = 0$, which makes $H$ an indefinite matrix at $P$. Hence, $P$ is a saddle point.
The case $g(x,y)$ is solved in the same way.

To be clear, for the Hessian to be indefinite, you must display both a positive and a negative eigenvalue. With a zero eigenvalue, the test is inconclusive. Consider $f(x,y) = x^2+y^4$ versus $f(x,y)=x^2+y^3$. So you need to clarify your answer a good deal.
